# Using pub serve with ASP.NET Core backend

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'm using Dart to build JS applications that are loaded on web pages hosted from an ASP.NET Core application, and I'm trying to establish a development workflow with either pub serve or potentially pub build that allows for debugging. I've seen some related posts, but I'm still stuck. This is what I've tried:

1. I used pub build with dart2js and the --mode=debug flag set to generate dart sources and a sourceMap, and then used Chrome to load and debug the web pages. The problem here, apart from long compile times, is the sourceMaps don't seem to work well for the debugging. Lines in the .dart files are often unavailable for debugging, and stepping over function calls doesn't work well, instead diving into framework code. I'm also unable to see values reported reliably.
2. I used pub get with the --packages-dir flag to copy in dependencies and then loaded the web pages with Dartium hosted by the IIS Express server. This loads pages fine and lets me develop, but I was unable to get breakpoints working at all in Dartium unless I used the debugger() statement directly in my code. I'm also concerned about this approach in general because Dartium is no longer being updated and the Dart team's plan is to move away from it.
3. As an offshoot of #2, I also tried simply changing my script tag URLs in my ASP.NET pages to point to the resources on the pub serve dev server. This is blocked because pub serve apparently only serves on http, and the ASP.NET application is hosted via HTTPS locally. I tried to change the backend to load on HTTP, but now I'm running into issues with authentication/authorization not working in my .NET app. Also, I had hoped to be able to use dartdevc with this approach, but that gave me 404 errors with requirejs, I think because it was trying to load it from the IIS Express server instead of pub serve (I'm really not sure about that).

I've found some mentions in other StackOverflow posts of setting up some sort of proxying behavior in order to have a backend server request resources from pub serve, but I have no idea how this might be done or if it applies to this situation. I can't find any information.

What strategies are people using for this, and is there a best-practice in mind going forward with Dart 2.0 and dartdevc?

Comment: I didn't realize Chrome has an option to override the insecure mixed content blocker, so option 3 with Dartium is a workable hack for now.

Comment: I think the best optiin is to set up a proxy using Nginx or a Dart script in between the browser and the server that redirects requests to `pub serve` or ASP.NET depending on the path

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try to find some information on how to do that.